# Insert Data into database via mySQL using visual studio in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, crud

So I'm trying to insert data into an SQL Database, which was created in Visual Studio 2017 via a Service-Based Database.

Here is the code

```
    private void save() { 
        Book book = new Book();
        book.Id = System.Convert.ToInt32(idtxtbox.Text);
        book.title = titletxtbox.Text;
        book.author = authortxtbox.Text;

        string query = "INSERT INTO Book VALUES(" + System.Convert.ToInt32(idtxtbox.Text) + "," + titletxtbox.Text + "," + authortxtbox.Text + ")";

        using (conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) {
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();// Error here
            conn.Close();
        }
            clear();
    }
```

If I enter data like

```
id = 001
title = "The Book"
Author = "Main Author"
```

I get an error that says " System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Book'.' ". What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have denoted the line where I get an error by the text "Error here" in the method included in this post

Comment: You're missing single quotes around `titletxtbox.Text` & `authortxtbox.Text`. It should be `"INSERT INTO Book (Id, Title, Author) VALUES (" + System.Convert.ToInt32(idtxtbox.Text) + ",'" + titletxtbox.Text + "','" + authortxtbox.Text + "')"`.

Comment: Normally in SQL you would say `INSERT INTO Book(Id, Title, Author) VALUES(a, 'b','c')`

Comment: Of course you also have a problem where your code is susceptible to sql injections...

Comment: The tiniest bit of research would have found thousands of posts here related to this sort of error and the ***ubiquitous*** admonition to *always use SQL parameters*

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way and thus avoid sql injections:

```
 SqlConnection conexion;

 private void save() {

    conexion = cConexion.getConexion(); 

    SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand();
    comand.Connection = conexion;
    comand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Book(Id, title, author) VALUES(@Id, @title, @author)";
    comand.Parameters.Add("Id", SqlDbType.Int, 3).Value = this.idtxtbox.Text;
    comand.Parameters.Add("title", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = this.titletxtbox.Text;
    comand.Parameters.Add("author", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = this.authortxtbox.Text;
    comand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    clear();
 }
```

I like to use a connection class to handle the connections

```
class cConexion
{
    private static SqlConnection conexion;

    public static SqlConnection getConexion()
    {
        if (conexion != null)
        {
            return conexion;
        }
        conexion = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString);
        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            return conexion;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error" + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void cerrarConexion()
    {
        if (conexion != null)
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
    }
}
```